# Your app is not optimized for iphone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uploading

[image]I have uploaded my app to store in the first time without any problem. But I tried the next version it shows the error as in the screenshot.

[image]

I have given the correct image size.

**iphone potrait 8**

- Retina hd 5.5 - Default - 1004h@2x.png
- Retina hd 4.7 - Default-1334h.png

**iphone potrait 7, 8**

- (2x) - Default-960h.png
- Retina 4 - Default-568h@2x.png

**iphone potrait 5,6**

- 1x - Default-568h.png
- 2x - Default-960h-1.png
- retina 4 - Default-568h@2x-1.png

the error persists.  help me?

Comment: images located at the top level of your bundle?

Comment: Checkout [this](http://dannysu.com/2014/04/16/not-optimized-for-iphone5/) link, I think it will solve your issue. Please do tell if it does.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is.

1. Set launch image in info.plist. See image. [image]
2. Go to images.xcasses in your project create launch image for all devices screen. See image [image]

If you support for ios 8 and 9. You should create file Launch screen.xib and set in project seting. See image [image]

I think you will solve your problem.